# How to copy all the artifacts from source to destination in Multi Stage Docker File

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have two stages as follow:

**Stage # 1**

```
    FROM mongo:latest AS mongodb
    ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME root
    ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD root
    ENV MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE admin
    ADD mongo-init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**Stage # 02**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y supervisor nginx &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/
COPY --from=mongodb #How can I copy all artifacts from source to destination

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Both of these stages are working perfectly separately. How can I copy all the artifacts from first stage to second stage?

Comment: I deleted my answer hence I was completely off topic. I don't know to answer your question. If the requirements ask you to run several processes in the same container, perhaps the solution should not be based on Docker.

Comment: I understand. Thank you :) @NeoAnderson you are always quick.

Comment: I'd almost always expect this to run in two separate containers (and let Docker play the role you're trying to use `supervisord` for here).  You can't merge two different images like this.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got it that I cant merge images like this. But If I use above structure in this way Like 2 From Statements then mongodb does not connect because its not in the last stage.

Comment: Right, you need to separately `docker run mongo` or use a tool like Docker Compose that can run multiple containers together.